# Intrusion detection

Tags: remote

In this day & age, it is almost impossible to detect who is lurking in the background in our system while we use our Ubuntu desktop / Laptop.

Any idea of how to detect such intrusion or how to block it from happening.

I am not a programmer - rather a mid-level user.

thanks

Comment: First, ensure that you have security updates enabled. Second, audit the services that listen upon open ports; uninstall services you don't use. Third, use ordinary safe browsing and e-mail habits to prevent the most common vectors of malware installation. Fourth, encrypt sensitive information...or simply don't put sensitive information on internet-facing machines. Fifth, power off unused machines instead of simply sleeping them. Lots more.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking for the users running processes, using a simple

```
ps -eo user | sort | uniq -c
```

that does the following:

1. prints any user name that is running anything on your pc
2. sort this list descending (by username)
3. count how many processes each user is running.

For example on my pc (my username is `davide`) the output is

```
ps -eo user | sort | uniq -c

      2 avahi
      1 colord
    113 davide
     34 gdm
      1 geoclue
      2 kernoops
      1 messagebus
    167 root
      1 rtkit
      1 syslog
      1 systemd-resolve
      1 systemd-timesync
      1 USER
      1 uuidd
      1 whoopsie
```

Then I can investigate this more, for example if I want to know what avahi is doing:

```
ps axu | grep avahi

avahi     1176  0.0  0.0  47264  3128 ?        Ss   21:26   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [brenna.local]
avahi     1186  0.0  0.0  47076   336 ?        S    21:26   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
```

Comment: thanks, David I assume it is similar to the GUI based "System Monitor".

Comment: thanks, David I assume it is similar to the GUI based "System Monitor". I was thinking like an app like virus detectors - a pop-up window warning of unauthorized intruders. in days so many scammers lurking around - only experts can detect such unauthorized intrusion.